# How to append javascript array of functions from other js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of functions like this:

```
var myFuncs = {
firstFun: function(string) {
// do something},
secondFunc: function(string) {
// do something},
thirdFunc: function(string) {
// do something
}}
```

What I want is, for example, to put the first two functions, firstFun{} and 
secondFunc{}, into separate js file, firstsecondFun.js using jQuery function or other approaches talked in [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

```
var myFuncs = {
jQuery.getScript("firstsecondFun.js", function(){
alert("Script loaded and executed.");
// // Here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script
}),
thirdFunc: function(string) {
// do something
}};p
```

firstsecondFun.js will be like:

```
firstFun: function(string) {
// do something},
secondFunc: function(string) {
// do something}
```

either with or without var myFuncs = {} so in the end the var myFuncs = {} will just the same as all functions in it.

I tried myFuncs.push but it does not work.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ or just plain old `foo.bar = wow;`

Comment: try to implement it using object instead of array you'll get what you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided content of firstseconfFun.js would be:

```
var firstSecond = {
  firstFun: function(string) {},
  secondFunc: function(string) {}
}
```

Then, in your main file, put this code.

```
var myFuncs = {
  thirdFunc: function(string) {
    // do something
  }
}

jQuery.getScript("firstsecondFun.js", function(){
  for(var k in firstSecond) {
    myFuncs[k] = firstSecond[k]
  }
});
```

I haven't tested, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Would the code in the last paragraph overwrite the "thirdFunc" since myFuncs[0] = thirdFunc?

Comment: No. it won't overwrite. And `myFuncs[0]` is not `thirdFunc`. `myFuncs` is not an array but an object. `myFuncs['thirdFunc']` is the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the object `myfuncs` you can simply add new properties using object notation.

```
var myFuncs = {
   firstFun: function(string) { /* do something*/}
}
```

in another file loaded after first file

```
myFuncs.secondFunc = function(string) {  /* do something else*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not array. but 
you can use class in javascript to do it :) ...

```
function myFuncs(){
      this.firstFun = function(string){
      /* do something*/
      }
      this.secondFunc = function(string){
      /* do something*/
      }
      this.thirdFunc = function(string){
      /* do something*/
      }
}
```

how to use it:

```
var curFuncs= new myFuncs();
curFuncs.firstFun(/* string value */);
or curFuncs.secondFunc(/* string value */);
or curFuncs.thirdFunc(/* string value */);
```